# Shared access tokens in a distributed system

Tags: authentication, design-patterns, architecture, distributed-computing

'm building a system that horizontally scales with many nodes. Any of these nodes could consume an API that's hosted on https://example.com/api. The authentication for this API is token based.

My question is, should each of my nodes authenticate separately and fetch their own token? Or should I build a shared cache between them and store the token there?

If latter, are there any standards for this design pattern, or better yet libraries that can do this for me? ie. stores the token in cache, and takes a lambda function + ttl for auth or renewal)

Thanks!

Comment: scaling allows you to avoid an issue of single point of failure. Introduction of shared access token takes your system design back to SPOF. I advice you to use individual access tokens for each node. This will probably also give you an benefit of analysis of API usage per node.